# Merge Management Not Working with more than two input

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I have code to merge two featureclasses with Merge_Management geoprocessing tool using ArcObject.

Below is the code :

```c#
 for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                if (map.Layer[i].Name == "HT Overhead Line")
                {   ILayer HTOverheadLine = map.Layer[i];
                    IFeatureLayer fl1 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                    fl1 = HTOverheadLine as IFeatureLayer;                                      
                    IDataset dataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)(HTOverheadLine);
                    STR = dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)fl1.FeatureClass).BrowseName;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (map.Layer[i].Name == "HT Underground Line")
                    {
                        ILayer HTUndergroundLine = map.Layer[i];
                        IFeatureLayer fl2 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                        fl2 = HTUndergroundLine as IFeatureLayer;                            
                        IDataset dataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)(HTUndergroundLine);
                        STR = STR + ";" + dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)fl2.FeatureClass).BrowseName;
                    }

                }

            }
            IGeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
            gp.AddOutputsToMap = true;
            gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
            IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();

            parameters.Add(STR);               
            //MessageBox.Show(STR);
            parameters.Add(@"outpath\Merge.shp");
            gp.Execute("Merge_management", parameters, null);
```

This is working fine and merges the two featureclasses, however when I am trying to merge three featureclasses, it gives a strange error with below code

```c#
 for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
        {
            if (map.Layer[i].Name == "HT Overhead Line")
            {   ILayer HTOverheadLine = map.Layer[i];
                IFeatureLayer fl1 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                fl1 = HTOverheadLine as IFeatureLayer;                                      
                IDataset dataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)(HTOverheadLine);
                STR = dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)fl1.FeatureClass).BrowseName;
            }
            else
            {
                if (map.Layer[i].Name == "HT Underground Line")
                {
                    ILayer HTUndergroundLine = map.Layer[i];
                    IFeatureLayer fl2 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                    fl2 = HTUndergroundLine as IFeatureLayer;                            
                    IDataset dataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)(HTUndergroundLine);
                    STR = STR + ";" + dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)fl2.FeatureClass).BrowseName;
                }
                else
                      {
                          if (map.Layer[i].Name == "LT Underground Line")
                          {
                              ILayer LTUndergroundLine = map.Layer[i];
                              IFeatureLayer fl3 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                              fl3 = LTUndergroundLine as IFeatureLayer;

                              IDataset dataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)(LTUndergroundLine);
                              STR = STR + ";" + dataset.Workspace.PathName + "\\" + ((IDataset)fl3.FeatureClass).BrowseName;

                          }

            }

        }
        IGeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
        gp.AddOutputsToMap = true;
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
        IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();

        parameters.Add(STR);               
        //MessageBox.Show(STR);
        parameters.Add(@"outpath\Merge.shp");
        gp.Execute("Merge_management", parameters, null);
```

I do not understand whats wrong between these two codes?

Comment: I find that when merge fails it is due to some of the fields in the layers. For example if the first layer has a field named "Comment" and it is 50 characters long and layer two has a "Comment" field that is 100 characters long, that is just one way where this can go wrong. Try the offending merge in the desktop and see if there is a problem there!

Comment: In the case of the "LT Under.." you're casting an ILayer to an IDataset - **no this will not work**, your feature layer in this block is fl3 not LTUndergroundLine. Note that IFeatureLayer has a property FeatureClass which has a property of  FeatureDataset so you mightn't need to cast. It is possible that the names of the layers aren't quite matching. C, in its various forms, is a case sensitive language so "LT Under" != "LT under", it would be a good idea to get into the habit of comparing strings as either upper or lower or one day it will come back to bite you.

Comment: I would suggest using a List <String> MergeNames = new List <String>() {"lt under..line","ht under..line","ht over..line"}; (see https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list) then write *just one block* using if MergeName.Contains(map.Layer[i].Name.ToLower()) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) as the condition. That way there's just *one* block to validate and you can add or remove as simply as changing the list.